# Pushing object correctly formatted for firebase database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want the following structure on firebase db.

```
"thumbnails": {
    "72": "http://url.to.72px.thumbnail",
   "144": "http://url.to.144px.thumbnail"
}
```

I am having hard time getting the keys 72, 144 in the structure correctly as they are calculated values before the push to the db. They represent the pixels of an image.

```
let pixel = this.calcPixels();

let obj = ?????

var updates = {};
updates['/guid/thumbnails/'] = obj;

let masterRef = this.db.database.ref();
masterRef.update(updates);
```

What i am trying to do is the following but this does not work obviously.

```
let obj = { pixel : this.getUrl()}
```

I can create a class to send but the class members names(pixelx,urlx) will end up being the key on the server.

```
class PixelData{
  pixelx:number;
  urlx:string;

  constructor(p:number,u:string){
    this.pixelx = p;
    this.urlx = u;
  }
}
```

setting this obj results in the following (pushing - with firebase push id under thumbnails)

```
"thumbnails": {
  "pixelx": 72
  "urlx": "http://url.to.72px.thumbnail",
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
let obj = { pixel : this.getUrl()}
```

to

```
let obj = { [pixel] : this.getUrl()}
```

In your case, it's taking pixel as a string while in the latter case, it will take the value of the pixel variable.